# Improve calculation of function for big values by using unit disk values of it.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, approximation, transformation

Lets consider anlaytical function power series expansion.

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$$

Assume that this function convergent in any point of complex plane.

But for big values of $x$ this function will require more calculations to get to some approximate value, and accordingly for small $x$, the approximation would be reached much quicker.
For example:
In order to calculate the $e^5$ with
$$\sum_{i=0}^{12}\frac{5^i}{i!}=148.114$$
While
$$e^5=148.413$$
So we reached 3-digit accuracy.

Now if we do the same for $e^{1/5}$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{12}\frac{1}{5^i i!}=1.22140275816017$$

16 digits of which are accurate.

Now the question is if there is a known method of accelerating calculations of function in some point (for example $e^5$) using some transformation to the unit disk (using calculations of $e^x$ for $x<1$)?

---

Here is a useful link, unfortunatley the methods described here does not work for my case.
http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/seriesacceleration.html#Cohen

Comment: Well, in that particular case we can calculate $a=e^{1/5}$ and then $a^{25}$. But I guess you want something a little more general. ;) Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_transformation_of_series

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation BTW, a math library would probably calculate $e^5$ using something like $(e^{5/8})^8$, since binary division & binary powers are easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for comments, I have checked some acceleration methods, of course here are some links, but those are not working for my case, so looking for other methods.  http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/seriesacceleration.html#Cohen

Comment: Gevorg, you should edit that info into your question. It's *always* a good idea to include prior research in Stack Exchange questions! And to get specific help with your problem you need to tell us what function you're trying to evaluate.

Comment: You may find something useful by searching with the key phrase of "range reduction", also known as "argument reduction".